# R masking conflict: packages bnlearn and sna

Tags: r, sna, bnlearn

I have problems to parallely use R packages `bnlearn` and `sna`. The following example is straightforward:

```
library(bnlearn)
data("asia")

# build network
a <- hc(asia)

# output
a
```

The output is as expected:

```
  Bayesian network learned via Score-based methods

  model:
   [A][S][T][L|S][B|S][E|T:L][X|E][D|B:E] 
  nodes:                                 8 
  arcs:                                  7 
    undirected arcs:                     0 
    directed arcs:                       7 
  average markov blanket size:           2.25 
  average neighbourhood size:            1.75 
  average branching factor:              0.88 

  learning algorithm:                    Hill-Climbing 
  score:                                 BIC (disc.) 
  penalization coefficient:              4.258597 
  tests used in the learning procedure:  77 
  optimized:                             TRUE
```

Once I load the `sna` package, I receive something completely different:

```
library(sna)

#output
a
```

I get:

```
Biased Net Model

Parameters:

Error in matrix(c(x$d, x$pi, x$sigma, x$rho), ncol = 1) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

As I don't really call any functions (just want to get the output of `a`), I don't think that using the `::` operator can help.

I wonder if the problem is masking of an internal function that I can't really influence. Any help would be great!

Comment: `sna` also has a `print.bn` method. So you can call explicitly `bnlearn:::print.bn(a)` (ps you can tell what `print` method is *likely* to be called by looking at `class(a)`, which leads to `print.bn`. Then look in `sna` to see if it also has a `print.bn` method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to other [q & a's](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D++masked+functions) except in this case there is an implicit call to `print`, rather than an explicit function call. It is this `print` function that is getting masked.

To print `a`, you can either type `a` in the terminal, or be explicit and type `print(a)`. To get the nice print layout of the `bn` object, the author has written a `print` method, and this is what is dispatched when typing either `a` or `print(a)`. (To see it without this specific printing you can use `print.default(a)`). After noting that the `class(a) == "bn"`, you can look for the `print` method, by using `methods("print")` or typing `bnlearn:::print` and then `<tab>` to see available functions: this leads to a (non-exported) function `bnlearn:::print.bn`.

So long story short, the `sna` package also has a `print.bn` method, for objects of `class` `"bn"` (biased net), and it is this function that masks the one from `bnlearn`.

So if you load `sna` after `bnlearn`, you can still get the nice printing by either explicitly using `bnlearn:::print.bn(a)`, or redefine the `print` method `print.bn <- bnlearn:::print.bn`, and it should print as expected.